# Logic Apps liquid template ask

Tags: azure-logic-apps, liquid-template

I am a complete newcomer to Liquid, started playing with it a few hours ago.

i am trying to parse a JSON and extract certain key value pairs out of it, yet i am not successful at all. the JSON is outputed from Azure Form Recognizer, and i am trying to do a Liquid json 2 json in Logic Apps.

the JSON looks like this

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "pages": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "keyValuePairs": [
        {
          "key": [
            {
              "text": "Page No:",
              "boundingBox": [
                507.4
               ]
            }
          ],
          "value": [
            {
              "text": "1",
              "boundingBox": [
                586.8
              ],
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
....
...
```

what i am looking for is to loop through the keyValuePairs array, and then pull the "text" element from the "key" array, and the "text"+"confidence" element from the "value"array.

Could you please help me in understanding the approach here? I tried something like this, but the array comes back empty

```
{
"results":[
{% for kvp in content.keyValuePairs  %}

{% for mykey in kvp.key  %}

"thiskey":"{{mykey.text}}
{%- endfor -%}
{% for myval in kvp.value  %}

"thisvalue":{{myval.text}}
"thisconfidence":{{myval.confidence}}
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
]
}
```

And second question: what's the best approach for debugging Liquid, so i can see where i am getting it wrong and adjust?

Thank you!

Comment: If in case, you only want to access the JSON property, then go ahead and use Parse JSON action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sample of json data and the liquid template you provided, I know there are more than one object under the property `keyValuePairs` in your json data. So I think using "Parse JSON" action is not a good solution for it, we'd better use liquid template as you mentioned in your question. But I'm confused about that if there are more than one object under the property `pages` in your json data ?

Now I assume the json data just has one object under the property `pages` and provide the solution of liquid template for your reference (If the json data has more than one object under the property `pages`, please provide some more details of your requirements and I will modify my solution).

I assume your json data like below:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "pages": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "keyValuePairs": [
                {
                    "key": [
                        {
                            "text": "Page No:",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                507.4
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "text": "1",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                586.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 1.0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": [
                        {
                            "text": "Page No:",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                507.4
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "text": "2",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                586.8
                            ],
                            "confidence": 2.0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**1.** We need to get the object under the property `pages` and put it in the "content" of "Transform JSON to JSON" action. We can parse the whole json data(with "Parse JSON" action) first and do something like below:
[image]

**2.** Upload the liquid template to integration account, please refer to my liquid template:

```
{
    "results":[
        {% for kvp in content.keyValuePairs  %}
            {%- if forloop.Last == true -%}
                {
                    {% for mykey in kvp.key  %}
                        "thiskey": "{{mykey.text}}",
                    {%- endfor -%}
                    {% for myval in kvp.value  %}
                        "thisvalue": "{{myval.text}}",
                        "thisconfidence": "{{myval.confidence}}"
                    {%- endfor -%}
                }
            {%- else -%}
                {
                    {% for mykey in kvp.key  %}
                        "thiskey": "{{mykey.text}}",
                    {%- endfor -%}
                    {% for myval in kvp.value  %}
                        "thisvalue": "{{myval.text}}",
                        "thisconfidence": "{{myval.confidence}}"
                    {%- endfor -%}
                },
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
    ]
}
```

**3.** After running this logic, we can get the result as:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "thiskey": "Page No:",
      "thisvalue": "1",
      "thisconfidence": "1"
    },
    {
      "thiskey": "Page No:",
      "thisvalue": "2",
      "thisconfidence": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Something you need to be aware of:**

1. Since we put the object under the property `pages` to the content of "Transform JSON to JSON" action, so the `content` in the liquid template represents it.
2. In liquid template, we need to be careful about the comma character, so I use `{%- if forloop.Last == true -%}` to judge if it is the last object in the loop, and then judge if we need to add the comma character.

For your second question about `what's the best approach for debugging Liquid ?`, unfortunately I think we can just complete the liquid template and upload to the integration account, then we can see the result. I don't know if there is a way for us to debug it easily.

Hope it helps~

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to design workflow using your sample JSON payload.

I have parsed the JSON schema and extracted the required values from it.

Since your JSON payload is a bit complex, we need to use Logic App Expressions to extract the value out of it.

**Payload I used**:

```
{
"status": "success",
"pages": [{
    "number": 1,
    "keyValuePairs": [{
            "key": [{
                "text": "Page No:",
                "boundingBox": [
                    507.4
                ]
            }],
            "value": [{
                "text": "1",
                "boundingBox": [
                    586.8
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }]
        },
        "null"
    ]
}]
```

}

Once you get the JSON output from the upstream actions, you have to parse it.

[image]

Now, Initialize a couple of variables to get the required value from the parsed JSON.

**Expression to be used in the first variable**: concat(body('Parse_JSON')?['pages'][0]?['keyValuePairs'][0]?['key'][0]?['text'],body('Parse_JSON')?['pages'][0]?['keyValuePairs'][0]?['value'][0]?['text'])

**Expression to be used in the second variable**: body('Parse_JSON')?['pages'][0]?['keyValuePairs'][0]?['value'][0]?['confidence']

[image]

Finally, the logic apps after your Form Recognizor will look something like this:

[image]

I hope it helps!